# Como identificar exatamente qual registro mudou de uma lista para outra? Pelo ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array

Olá.

Tenho 2 listas sendo montadas em javascript, baseado na regra:

- tem flag consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente como true no banco?
  Então fica no Array: clientesDownloadTrue
- tem flag consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente como false no banco?
  Então fica no Array: clientesDownloadFalse

A tela é esta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao enviar, quero conseguir saber exatamente qual registro foi para um lado ou outro?

Segue meu javascript:

```
app.controller("ConfiguraDownloadAutomatico",

    function($scope, $http,$filter,dialogMessage) {

        $scope.clientes = [];
        $scope.clientesDownloadFalse= [];
        $scope.clientesDownloadTrue =[];

        // picklist
        $scope.selectedA = [];
        $scope.selectedB = [];
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.checkedA = false;
        $scope.checkedB = false;

        /**
         * Obter sessão
         */
        $scope.loadSession = function() {

            $http({
                method : 'GET',
                url : 'session'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                $scope.idUsuario = response.data.result.id_usuario;
                $scope.iniciar();   

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response.data);

            });

        };
        $scope.loadSession();

        $scope.iniciar = function() {
            $http.post('obterEmpresasDownload', $scope.idUsuario).success(function(response) {

                $scope.clientes = response;
                $scope.items = response;
                angular.forEach($scope.clientes, function(value, key){
                    if(value.consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente == true){
                        $scope.clientesDownloadTrue.push(value);
                    }else{
                        $scope.clientesDownloadFalse.push(value);
                    }
                  });                 
            }); 
        };



        $scope.preparaInsercao = function(clientesDownloadFalse, clientesDownloadTrue) {

            var dados = {
                    clientesDownloadFalse : $scope.clientesDownloadFalse,
                    clientesDownloadTrue : $scope.clientesDownloadTrue
            };

            $http.post(
                    'configuradownload/salvarEmpresasDownloadAutomatico',
                    dados).then(
                    function(response) {
                        if (response.data.codReturn == 0) {
                            dialogMessage("Configura Download Automático",
                                    response.data.descReturn, "success");
                        } else {
                            dialogMessage("Configura Download Automático",
                                    response.data.descReturn, "erro");
                        }

                    }, function(response) {

                    });

        };  

            function arrayObjectIndexOf(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
                for(var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
                    if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) return i;
                }
                return -1;
            }

            $scope.aToB = function() {
              for (i in $scope.selectedA) {
                var moveId = arrayObjectIndexOf($scope.items, $scope.selectedA[i], "idCliente"); 
                $scope.clientesDownloadTrue.push($scope.items[moveId]);
                var delId = arrayObjectIndexOf($scope.clientesDownloadFalse, $scope.selectedA[i], "idCliente"); 
                $scope.clientesDownloadFalse.splice(delId,1);
              }
              reset();
            };

            $scope.bToA = function() {
              for (i in $scope.selectedB) {
                var moveId = arrayObjectIndexOf($scope.items, $scope.selectedB[i], "idCliente"); 
                $scope.clientesDownloadFalse.push($scope.items[moveId]);
                var delId = arrayObjectIndexOf($scope.clientesDownloadTrue, $scope.selectedB[i], "idCliente"); 
                $scope.clientesDownloadTrue.splice(delId,1);
              }
              reset();
            };

            function reset(){
              $scope.selectedA=[];
              $scope.selectedB=[];
              $scope.toggle=0;
            }

            $scope.toggleA = function() {

              if ($scope.selectedA.length>0) {
                $scope.selectedA=[];
              }
              else {
                for (i in $scope.clientesDownloadFalse) {
                  $scope.selectedA.push($scope.clientesDownloadFalse[i].idCliente);
                }
              }
            }

            $scope.toggleB = function() {

              if ($scope.selectedB.length>0) {
                $scope.selectedB=[];
              }
              else {
                for (i in $scope.clientesDownloadTrue) {
                  $scope.selectedB.push($scope.clientesDownloadTrue[i].idCliente);
                }
              }
            }

            $scope.selectA = function(i) {
              $scope.selectedA.push(i);
            };

            $scope.selectB = function(i) {
                $scope.selectedB.push(i);
            };


    });
```

Ao salvar, chama a função preparaInsercao que pega as listas, manda pro meu controller java e lá salvo o objeto.

Caso necessitem de mais informações, posto na hora. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu modelo pode ser simplificado. O exemplo funcional abaixo possui apenas uma coleção, `$scope.dados`, cujos itens possuem a propriedade booleana `consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente`.

Na view, tabelas que utilizam `ng-repeat` com filtro separam os dois tipos. Clique em uma linha para ter a propriedade invertida, e o item passado para a outra lista:

```js
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

app.controller('SampleController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.dados = [
    {
      "nome": "item1",
      "consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente": false
    },
    {
      "nome": "item2",
      "consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente": false
    },
    {
      "nome": "item3",
      "consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente": false
    },
    {
      "nome": "item4",
      "consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente": true
    },
    {
      "nome": "item5",
      "consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente": true
    },
    {
      "nome": "item6",
      "consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente": true
    },
  ]
});
```

```html
<html ng-app='sampleApp'>


  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="SampleController">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr><th>False</th></tr>
              <tr ng-repeat='i in dados | filter: { consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente : false }'>
                <td ng-click='i.consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente = !i.consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente'>{{i.nome}}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr><th>True</th></tr>
              <tr ng-repeat='i in dados | filter: { consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente : true }'>
                <td ng-click='i.consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente = !i.consultaNotasDestinadasAutomaticamente'>{{i.nome}}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```